# How to ensure 'channelRead' called once after each 'read' in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing an HTTP proxy server in Netty.

I would like `channelRead` to only be fired *at most once* after I call `read` --
 and at no other time. In other words, I don't want `channelRead` to fire until I'm ready for the message.

I have set `AUTO_READ=false`. I call `ctx.read()` once in `channelActive` (and nowhere else).

However, for a basic `curl http://localhost:8080/`, the `channelRead` handler fires twice:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpRequest
io.netty.handler.codec.http.LastHttpContent$1
```

How can I prevent `LastHttpContent` from arriving until I call `ctx.read()` for the second time?

Comment: I may have found the solution: `FlowControlHandler`: "The `FlowControlHandler` ensures that only one message per `read()` is sent downstream."... will check it out after dinner :D

Answer (score 3):

`FlowControlHandler` solves this problem: it's designed specifically to enable this behaviour.

From [the docs](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/flow/FlowControlHandler.html):

> The `FlowControlHandler` ensures that only one message per `read()` is
>   sent downstream.
>
> ...
>
> It's a common problem with the `HttpObjectDecoder` that will very
>   often fire a `HttpRequest` that is immediately followed by a
>   `LastHttpContent` event.
>
> `ChannelPipeline pipeline = ...;`
>
> `pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());`
>
> `pipeline.addLast(new FlowControlHandler());`
>
> `pipeline.addLast(new MyExampleHandler());`

Comment: The example inside the javadoc of that class seems to be cut off midway, do you have an example how to use it? (specifically, ido you still need to call `setAutoRead` when using that handler?)

Comment: In my case I have `AUTO_READ=false`, but that only means "don't auto read from the socket", so if an encoder produces multiple messages for a chunk of received data (such as the `HttpDecoder` does) then you'll still get 2-or-more messages arriving at your handler. The `FlowControlHandler` helps in these cases. Also note that most decoders will automatically perform a `read` even if you have `AUTO_READ=false` since they need to read enough data in order to yield at least one message to subsequent (i.e. your) handlers... but after they yield a message, they won't auto-read from the socket again.